# Skyrim on parallels

Tags: parallels-desktop, games

Will I be able to play Skyrim in Parallels?

These are my specs:

http://cl.ly/0o3l2Z2w2I422k2o101D

Bootcamp is a non-starter for me (too lazy).

Thanks!

Comment: This question is very localized. Since your system configuration is so specific, this is unlikely to be helpful to others. If you can reframe the question in a way that is more widely applicable please feel free to do so and ask that. Please take a look at the [FAQs](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq) for more info. Thanks.

Comment: @Nathan, millions of people have my system. But okay

Comment: @NathanGreenstein Parallels is not specific to him but a common platform. You are being ridiculously obtuse closing this topic. Lot of people have Macs, but since this is a virtualized environment (even though specific to Macs) is is a very common and non-specific environment.

Comment: To answer the question, I have it running, but had to turn all detail off... I am not sure which details are needed and which are causing the crash... if this Stack was actually useful for Mac discussions I would start one there, but it obviously is not. I will try and start a thread for this someplace else.

Comment: @Marius did parallels crash or did skyrim crash? Thanks for the info, I'd appreciate any updates!

Comment: I tested it on my 2011 iMac (2.7GHz i5, Radeon 6770M) and it ran pretty poorly, even at Low detail. Looks like it'll be Boot Camp for this one.

Comment: @Harry, Parallels crashed, but I think I messed with fullscreen and Coherence modes a bit. Running it as dedicated fullscreen have proven to be stable. However funning it fullscreen on my 27" iMac proved to be slow because of the immense resolution. And I found that if I scale my resolution down I get the greatest speed increase even if I leave all other settings on Ultra.

Comment: However, after playing a bit, I decided to give BootCamp a install and try it out there. Not many games out there that I would do this for... and it ran like a dream natively on Windows Bootcamp. I have a top-end i7 iMac with 2GB of video ram and 12GB of RAM running it on 2560x1440 with all on Ultra. For anyone who really likes the game and want to see how good it can look, I would advise this.

Comment: @Marius which version of Windows did you try this on? I'm about to try out Skyrim on Boot Camp for myself.

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL I'm running it on Windows 7 on Bootcamp and VM. Used to use Vista, and it ran fine in that as well.

Comment: @Harry the link is broken, please [edit]